# Apache: DocumentRoot set on symlink, points on the actual file?

Tags: apache, unix, symlink

I'm building a deployment script and something seems wrong in the way Apache deals with my symlink.

I have a folder containing:

- `foo_svn`: folder (my current website)
- `foo_tmp`: folder (a copy)
- `web`: symlink (pointing on foo_svn)

My DocumentRoot is set on `web`.

Before svnupdating `foo_svn`, I backup the contents in `foo_tmp` and I replace the symlink so that it points on `foo_tmp`.

Then I update `foo_svn`: let's say `index.php` has been modified. The website should be the same, since it now points on `foo_tmp` and that folder hasn't changed. And yet the page displayed is the new one, as if Apache looked directly for `foo_svn/index.php` instead of `web/index.php`.

In the vhost config file, DocumentRoot is still `.../web`, same as in the `<Directory>`. The symlink `web` still points on `foo_tmp`, and `foo_tmp/index.php` is still the old version.

**EDIT:** Digging a little deeper, it looks like there's something really weird with some kind of cache. Hard-reloading my page two times, sometimes it points first on foo_tmp, then on foo_svn, then on foo_tmp (then it stabilizes). Sometimes it just takes some time for the page to accept the new version (even hard-reloading). Sometimes it shows the new page in `foo_svn` *too early*, because the symlink is still pointing on the previous version in `foo_tmp`. I'm going insane over this, it's like Apache has a kind of "symlink cache," I don't know.

Comment: Possibly related: http://serverfault.com/questions/294107/apache-php-appears-to-be-caching-symbolic-links-for-60-seconds-how-to-stop-it
http://serverfault.com/questions/373944/apache-doesnt-immediately-notice-a-change-in-the-document-root